# Node exports across 3 files

Tags: javascript, node.js, modular

I have a file structure of this format:

index.js - requires the files below

> accounts.js
>   events.js
>   irc.js

Index is the file which is opened by nodejs, accounts has lots of useful code inside relating to an accounts system, events contains event handling code for stuff unrelated to IRC and accounts but irc initiated a connection to an IRC server but also contains some useful code to print any errors that happen via the ErrorLog function I have made.

I require irc.js in the index.js file but I would like to use the ErrorLog function in accounts.js too as well as events.js and potentially more files in the future which is required after I require irc.js.

How can I make it so irc.js is only included once (so the connection code isn’t triggered more than once) but useable in all other JS files?

Comment: The most confusing part is still unanswered, please see my reply below

Answer (score 1):

You can save the open connection in a variable in your irc.js file.

```
 let connection;

 export const getConnection = () => {
   if (!connection) connection = IRC.createConnection("XXXX");
   return connection; 
 }
```

Then everytime you will import {getConnection} from 'irc' you'll get the same connection.

Comment: Thanks but how can I use my ErrorLog function too in events.js & accounts.js? Am I going to have to require them in each file individually? And how would I write the exports code for a function?

Comment: @nootskej I think you should read about the difference between providers and instances What Shai gave you is a provider `getConnection()` that provides the instance `connection`.  You could read how JavaScript devs handles providers and factories (with libs like Angular) and use that same pattern in your code.